# Regular expression needed for "<!-- A-Za-z0-9 -->"

Tags: php, regex, html

Need help with regular expression for `<!-- A-Za-z0-9 -->` where all the uppercase, smallcase and digits are allowed. Need a regular expression to find this chunk including the comment tags (`<!--  -->`).

Comment: [<!\-\-A-Za-z0-9\-\->] but it's not working

Comment: that's not any code. would help if you put the code to pass the regular expression.

Comment: The html standard parses comments like this `<!--.*?-->`, its better to capture each comment and test for your string: `<!--(.*?)-->`, but rember, this can be in a CDATA block, and visa-versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[<!\-\-A-Za-z0-9\-\->]
```

This is a character class and the order doesn't matter in a character class. What will work however:

```
<!--\s*[A-Za-z0-9]+\s*-->
```

*If* you now want to include spaces inside the comment, you can use:

```
<!--\s*[A-Za-z0-9 ]+\s*-->
```

I used the `\s*` in case there are several white spaces between the `<!--` and `-->` and the part to capture.

Use `preg_match_all` and if you want to make the regex shorter, you can use the `i` flag. something like this:

```
preg_match_all('~<!--\s*[a-z0-9]+\s*-->~i', $page, $matches);
```

Comment: Awesome, it worked. Thank you. If I want to include special characters like '!@#$%^&*()' which are on top of number keys, do I need to escape them?

Comment: @BostonGuy If you want to include those, you replace `[a-z0-9]+` by `[a-z0-9!@#$%^&*()]+` Easy, yes? :) If you have \, -, or ], you'll need to escape them (well, not `-` if it's at the beginning or end of the character class, but if you're not sure, escape it)

Comment: Yes, I tried that but I got PHP error as below  
Severity: Warning

Message: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Unknown modifier '#'. It basically gave me error for all special characters.

Comment: You used `@` for the delimiters right? Use `~`, it's much less common than `@`. `preg_replace('~<!--\s*[a-z0-9!@#$%^&*()]+\s*-->~i', '', $thing);`

Answer (score 0):

This is all I can think of according to your question

`#<!--([A-Za-z0-9]*)-->#`

Comment: It also depends on which engine you are using.  PECL or PCRE?